# Enter a valid URL and try again : Salesforce Lightning Web Component Error

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce-lightning, lwc

> Hi all
>            I am using LNS(Lightning NavigationService) in LWC. I have created three buttons for New,Edit ,View in LWC on Account object where  i am adding my component in Account record where  i can clcik thee  buttons i.e. On click of New button it will open New Account record STandard Record Page similarly for rest of buttons edit & view. But when i am click on each of these buttons i am getting error msg "Enter a valid URL and try again".
>   Let me know what  ihave missed

Hi all
         I am using LNS(Lightning NavigationService) in LWC. I have created three buttons for New,Edit ,View in LWC on Account object where  i am adding my component in Account record where  i can clcik thee  buttons i.e. On click of New button it will open New Account record STandard Record Page similarly for rest of buttons edit & view. But when i am click on each of these buttons i am getting error msg "Enter a valid URL and try again".
Let me know what  ihave missed

```js
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import{NavigationMixin} from 'lightning/navigation'

export default class NavigationServiceLWC extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    navigateToNewRecordPage(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type:'standard__recordPage',
            attributes:{
                "recordId":this.recordId,
                "objectApiName":"Account",
                "actionName":"new"

            }
        });
    }
    navigateToEditRecordPage(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type:'standard__recordPage',
            attributes:{
                "recordId":this.recordId,
                "objectApiName":"Account",
                "actionName":"edit"

            }
        });
    }
    navigateToViewRecordPage(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type:'standard__recordPage',
            attributes:{
                "recordId":this.recordId,
                "objectApiName":"Account",
                "actionName":"view"

            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Navigation Service in Lightning Web Components">
    <lightning-card title="Navigate to Record Page">
      <lightning-button-group>
        <lightning-button label="New Record Page" onclick={navigateToNewRecordPage}></lightning-button>  
        <lightning-button label="Edit Record Page" onclick={navigateToEditRecordPage}></lightning-button>
        <lightning-button label="View Record Page" onclick={navigateToViewRecordPage}></lightning-button>
      </lightning-button-group>  
    </lightning-card>
  </lightning-card>  
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me as well, in my case however there was a casing issue in the ***recordid*** variable name

```
attributes:{
    "recordId": this.recordid,
    "objectApiName":"Account",
    "actionName":"view"
}
```

Edit - Can you post this question on [Salesforce's stackexchange?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/)